# Console.Readline("") repeating at restart

Tags: c#

I have this question,

My boss wants a program which you can enter a path, `Console.ReadLine(directory);`
This is irrelevant, I got this part working. In fact, the whole code/program is working as it should be.
The point of the path is that the program scans all the files in the given directory/subdirectories for the last write time. He want to pay minimum effort in this. So the plan is to use Windows to start this program once every 24 hours.
Only problem with this "minimum effort" part is that you have to enter the path EVERYTIME when it's started. So it actually doesn't go automaticly.

The question is: is there a way to avoid this?
For example `Thread.Sleep();` and when it's done sleeping goto a label right under the `Console.ReadLine(directory);`?

So not once a day, but sleeping for 24 hours and for 1 whole minute working?

If it's any help, here's the code:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace CheckWithinTime
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Which folder do you wish to scan?");
            string path = Console.ReadLine();

            //copies everything from the console to a .txt file
            FileStream filestream = new FileStream(@"C:\Logs\Log.txt", FileMode.Create);
                var streamwriter = new StreamWriter(filestream);
                streamwriter.AutoFlush = true;
                Console.SetOut(streamwriter);
                Console.SetError(streamwriter);

            //this is the path which you type in a the beginning of the program
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            List<string> updatedFiles = new List<string>();

            DateTime from = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            DateTime to = DateTime.Now;

            foreach (string name in files)
            {
                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(name);
                string fullname = file.FullName;

                //checks if the last writed time occured less then 24 hours ago, if it's not it will not be loggeed
                if (file.LastWriteTime >= from && file.LastWriteTime <= to)
                {
                    updatedFiles.Add(name);

                    Console.WriteLine(file.FullName + " ; " + "last changed at >>  " + " ; " + file.LastWriteTime.ToString());
                    //Console.WriteLine("File created at >>  " + file.CreationTime.ToString());
                    //Console.WriteLine("File last opened at >>  " + file.LastAccessTime.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }

            streamwriter.Close();
            filestream.Close();

            //The mail class basicly sends an e-mail to the server with the log file, but this is irrelevant
            Mail();
        }
    }
}
```

It used to be just a simple file system watcher. After that it was like it is now, but without the `Console.ReadLine()` part. And now he wants to give a path.

If anyone can tell me a way to avoid the `Console.ReadLine()`, but only use call it when you need it. I would appreciate it!

Sorry in advance for my big texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to either create an XML file or use a notepad file and have windows run a task manager.

You can set up a program to run every so often in windows task manager and all you need to do is save the path to a file and have your C# console application read that file and get the path, the path will always be store and the program will run all the time.

We do this at work; a program has been running for 4 months doing through a bunch of paths and we don't edit it anymore.

Comment: I totally forgot about this method! Haha that's super genius. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Xml file/config is overkill for one setting. Pass it in to the command line `string[] args`:

```
string path;
if(args.Length > 0)
{
  path = args[0];
  Console.WriteLine("Using path: " + path);
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("Which folder do you wish to scan?");
   path = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Then use task scheduler as already suggested, but pass the path as a command line argument. You can also then launch it with different paths without your app supporting multiple paths.

[image: Task scheduler with path to check argument]